# How could I reverse the bit order for signed integer in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, bit-manipulation

I have signed 16 bit integer data, range from [-32768:32767]
How could I reverse the order of bits for each sample ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
y = bin2dec(fliplr(dec2bin(mod(x, 65536), 16)));
```

This converts x to a 16 bit binary representation, reverses the binary representation, then converts this back to a value, y.

Comment: But isn't that only available for unsigned integer?

Comment: My bad - answer updated - now works for signed values.